# Why is MongoDB returning null when aggregate function $avg is used on a field

Tags: mongodb

I can't figure out why this query is not returning anything but null values, the fields have integers in them, some have null values but most have integers. I thought $avg ignored null values.
This is the query:

```
db.Companies.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:”$founded_year”,“avgNumEmployees”:{$avg:“$number_of_employees”}}},
    {$redact:{$cond:{if:{
        $eq:[“$avgNumEmployees”,“null”]},
        then: “$$PRUNE”,
        else:”$$KEEP”}
}}).pretty()
```

This some sample data from a document

```
_id: 52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d8a
name:"Wetpaint"
permalink:"abc2"
crunchbase_url:
"http://www.crunchbase.com/company/wetpaint"
homepage_url: "http://wetpaint-inc.com"
blog_url:
"http://digitalquarters.net/"
blog_feed_url:
"http://digitalquarters.net/feed/"
twitter_username:"BachelrWetpaint"
category_code:"web"
number_of_employees:47
founded_year:2005
founded_month:10
founded_day:17
deadpooled_year:1
tag_list:
"wiki, seattle, elowitz, media-industry, media-platform, social-distrib..."
```

This is one with a founded_year of null:

```
_id:52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d92
name:"Flektor"
permalink:"flektor"
crunchbase_url:
"http://www.crunchbase.com/company/flektor"
homepage_url:
"http://www.flektor.com"
blog_url:
"http://www.flektor-blog.com"
blog_feed_url:
"http://www.flektor-blog.com/video_editing_software/index.rdf"
twitter_username:
null
category_code:
"games_video"
number_of_employees:null
founded_year:null
founded_month:null
founded_day:null
deadpooled_year: null
deadpooled_month: null
deadpooled_day: null
deadpooled_url: null
```

This data is from mongoDB's sample training data set called companies.

Comment: Can you please add sample collection document on which you are getting null value.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your collection? and I think that `$avg` it's not your problem, and yes avg ignores non-numerical values.

Comment: @nicolaematies have updated the samples

Comment: What happens if you don't do redact ? everthing works ?